# How can the contents of batch files be transferred to notepad or excelsheet?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, batch-file, notepad, data-transfer

I have a list of batch files. I want to transfer all the contents of all files into a single notepad or excelsheet, making a list.

Comment: What version of Excel? If its 2003+ then go to the Data tab and look for "import file"

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in powershell.
Assuming all batch files are placed in 1 folder.

----- Copy and paste all text below this line into 1 scriptfile -----

```
#### Determine the location of all batchfiles
$BatchesFolder = "E:\Batches"

#### Determine the file for all collected data
$resultfile = "E:\Data\results.txt"

#### Read all files in batch folder
$batchfiles = (Get-ChildItem $BatchesFolder).fullname

#### Read each file and store data in result file
Foreach ($file in $batchfiles)
    {
    "--- Content of file $file ---" | Out-File -FilePath $resultfile -Append
    get-content $file | Out-File -FilePath $resultfile -Append
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cmd.exe`:

`type C:\PathToBatchFiles\* > C:\PathToOutputFolder\OutputFile.txt`

The contents of each file within the directory PathToBatchFiles will be printed to OutputFile.txt without any filename separators.

Answer (score 0):

This is from within Excel using *VBA*.

I have some *.bat* files in a folder called *Belfry*:

[image]

Running this *VBA* macro:

```
Sub BatLister()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim WhereToLook As String, FileName As String
    Dim fPath As String, FileSpec As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("bat dir")
    Set s2 = Sheets("bat list")
    s1.Cells.Clear
    s2.Cells.Clear
    WhereToLook = "C:\Users\garys\Documents\Belfry\*.bat"
    fPath = "C:\Users\garys\Documents\Belfry\"

    L = 1
    FileName = Dir(WhereToLook)
    FileSpec = fPath & FileName
    Do Until FileName = ""
        s1.Cells(L, 1) = FileSpec
        L = L + 1
        FileName = Dir()
        FileSpec = fPath & FileName
    Loop

    j = 1
    For i = 1 To L - 1
        FileSpec = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        s2.Cells(j, 1) = FileSpec
        j = j + 1
        Close #2
        Open FileSpec For Input As #2
        Do While Not EOF(2)
            Line Input #2, TextLine
            s2.Cells(j, 2) = TextLine
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Next i
    Close #2
End Sub
```

will produce a listing of all the *.bat* files in the folder.

The file names in column **A** and the file contents in column **B**:

[image]